# Class of the type Singleton as a container for objects

Tags: java, oop

I need to create objects that will be visible in the whole program (in various classes). I do not want to create Singletons for such classes because I might need a few instances. So I created a class of type Singleton as a container and inside it I created objects that I can use at any point in the program.
Below is a sample code where you see what's going on. Referring to an instance of `Container`, I will always have access to the facilities created there. I'm building a program to study. There will be big but I came up with the idea that has solutions to the problem. The problem was that the different controllers want an explicit object there any data. And then based on the full object perform calculations.

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(){    
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Container {

    private Person person1;
    private Person person2;

    private static Container singleton = new Container( );

    public Container() {
        person1 = new Person();
        person2 = new Person();
    }

    public Person getPerson1(){
        return person1;
    }

    public Person getPerson2(){
        return person2;
    }


    public static Container getInstance( ) {
          return singleton;
       }    
}
```

.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person;
        Container singleton = Container.getInstance();
        person = singleton.getPerson1();

        person.setName("John");


        Person personTest1;
        Container singleton2 = Container.getInstance();
        personTest1 = singleton2.getPerson1();

        System.out.println(personTest1.getName());
    }
}
```

Output:

John

It might not be the best solution but have not found as simple and quick solution as this. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand why do you really need the Container? It creates default Persons means there is no any business logic it uses and if yes than factory  design pattern is preferred.

Comment: In case you don't use any IoC/DI frameworks this solution is very reasonable. I would add `final` to `person1` and `person2` declarations to restrict their re-assignment. To make things even simpler you may 1. declare `person1` and `person2` as `static` fields and create them in static block or right in-place 2. Declare `getPerson` methods as `static` 3. In this case you can remove Container instance creation etc.

Comment: If the Container class is a singleton, it should have a private constructor.

Comment: This is just a sample code of the system of global visibility of the object. In my program I download different values in different windows (also in different controllers) in JavaFX. I join the data to the same object. The above code did only to illustrate the operation.

Answer (score 2):

I have just some remarks : `Container` which is your factory of `Person` should not be instantiable by client.
 Otherwise, client could create multiple versions of `person1` and `person2` .

Imagine this code :

```
    Container singleton = Container.getInstance();
    Person person = singleton.getPerson1();
    person.setName("John");


    Container singleton2 = new Container();
    Person personTest1 = singleton2.getPerson1();
    System.out.println(personTest1.getName());
```

To avoid that, you should make the constructor private.

```
public class Container {

    ...
    private Container() {
        person1 = new Person();
        person2 = new Person();
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Bartek it is not required to create the singleton in lazy. The singleton is instantiated as soon as the class is loaded here :   `private static Container singleton = new Container( );`

Comment: @programmerJavaPL I removed the second point about using or not static on `Person` fields. It is really a question of taste.What it really matters is what I said initially : making the constructor private to avoid breaking the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an enum here.

The code is cleaner and it is easier to extend with more Objects as you don't need to create a getter every time you add another.

As a bonus you don't have to worry about thread safety, eager initiation or exposing constructors.

```
    public enum Container {
        PERSON1(new Person()),
        PERSON2(new Person()),
        PERSON3(new Person()),
        PERSON4(new Person()),
        PERSONN(new Person());

        private final Person singleton;

        Container(final Person person) {
            this.singleton = Objects.requireNonNull(person);
        }
        public Person get(){
            return singleton;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person singletonA = Container.PERSON1.get();
        singletonA.setName("John");
        Person singletonB = Container.PERSON1.get();
        System.out.println(singletonB.getName());
    }
```